# deleting multiple elements without updating till the end

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
list_a = [1,5,8]
list_b = [12,4,2,5,7,5,3,6,8]
```

The elements in `list_a` correspond to the indices of elements in `list_b`. Both lists are of size greater than 100.

How can I delete the elements of `list_b` whose indices are in `list_a`,
so if you take the lists above the resulting list is `[12,2,5,7,3,6]`?

Comment: That was a mistake, thanks for telling me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two options:

- Create a new list with a list comprehension:

  ```
  newlist = [el for i, el in enumerate(oldlist) if i not in indices_to_delete]
  ```

  This will be all the faster if `indices_to_delete` was a `set`:

  ```
  indices_to_delete = set(indices_to_delete)
  newlist = [el for i, el in enumerate(oldlist) if i not in indices_to_delete]
  ```

  because membership testing in a set is O(1) vs. O(n) in a list.
- Remove the indices in reverse-sorted order from the list in-place:

  ```
  for index in sorted(indices_to_delete, reversed=True):
      del oldlist[index]
  ```

  If you *don't* remove items in reverse sorted order, items with higher indices are moved up as items with lower indices are removed and the rest of your `indices_to_delete` no longer match the items you needed to remove.

Answer (score 4):

This should accomplish that:

```
for delidx in reversed(toDelete):
  del otherList[delidx]
```

Also, using a list comprehension:

```
l2 = [elem for i, elem in enumerate(l1) if i not in toDelete]
```

Comment: Just a note: toDelete should first be sorted.

Comment: It was sorted in the question, was the only reason I didn't include it, but yes, that's a very good point.

Answer (score 2):

now that I understand the question

```
a = numpy.array(list2)
mask = [True]*len(a)
mask[list1] = False
print a[mask]
```

Comment: IIUC the OP wants to remove the elements *indexed* by list1.

Comment: ahh reading comprehension fail ... (on my part) ... think it should work now :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this a slightly over-engineered solution, but here it is

```
def get_newl(li, index):
    index = sorted(index, reverse=True)
    i=0
    while i < (len(li)-len(index)):
        x = index.pop()
        while i < x:
            yield li[i]
            i+=1
        i+=1
```

Run the code here http://codebunk.com/bunk#-Isxeb4TZOHBCvQi4EsY